# What is the range of integers produced by a Lehmer random number generator?

Tags: random

Wikipedia says the formula is [image] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator).

My assumption is that the range is anywhere from 1 to `n`, but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m mod n` produces numbers in the range [0, n-1]. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation.

Comment: For [1 .. n] output just add 1 to the returned random number.